# How to vertical align top in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 3 column divs inside a div.

I have something like

```
<div class="text-center">
   <div class="wrapper">
        <h5>title 1</h5>
       <div>
          item 1  
       </div>
       <div>
          item 2  
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="wrapper">
        <h5>title 2</h5>
       <div>
          item 1  
       </div>
       <div>
          item 2  
       </div>
       <div>
          item 3
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="wrapper">
        <h5>title 3</h5>
       <div>
          item 1  
       </div>
       <div>
          item 2  
       </div>
       <div>
          item 3  
       </div>
       <div>
          item 4  
       </div>
       <div>
          item 5
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

For some reason the `title 1` and `tile 2` column items are vertical align `bottom`. I was hoping to get all three column vertical aligned to `top`. I need to have `display:inline-block` style for this one instead of `float` because it will mess me up on other things. How do I do it?

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/f54Hh/

Comment: You've used `vertical-align` in previous questions, so you obviously know it exists.  What about your current situation makes it so it can't be used here?  Seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to your wrapper class:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f54Hh/7/)

Comment: One of the few times that property does what you think.

Comment: I'm confused, the answer was in the title of the question? Was it something that didn't cross OP's mind?